# How to use an affine transformation pipepline with GDAL Python API?

Tags: python, gdal, pyproj, osgeo, affine-transformation

I am trying to transform coordinates from a local grid to a projected coordinate system (UTM) to ultimately reproject raster or vector data.

I am using :

- Python 3.9
- GDAL 3.6.0
- Pyproj 3.4

I generated a test point dataset with local and real world coordinates in NAD83 UTM Z13 (EPSG:26913) for each point.

Three points from the dataset have been used to compute affine parameters to define a WKT2 transform based on the posts below:

[how-to-use-affine-transform-parameters-in-a-proj-or-wkt2-string](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387189/how-to-use-affine-transform-parameters-in-a-proj-or-wkt2-string)

[how-do-i-find-these-values-for-an-affine-transformation-state-plane-to-local-gr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403311/how-do-i-find-these-values-for-an-affine-transformation-state-plane-to-local-gr)

Base coordinates in NAD83 UTM Z13 (EPSG:26913)

```
    base = [[468000,6463900,0],[483000,6481880.76,0],[496856.41,6481880.76,0]]
```

Local grid coordinates

```
    local = [[0,0,0],[30000,0,0],[30000,16000,0]]
```

And the WKT2_2018 format affine transformation obtained from these points is:

```
    DERIVEDPROJCRS["survey_grid",BASEPROJCRS["NAD83 / UTM zone 13N",BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4269]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 13N",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-105,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],
    PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
    DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",ID["EPSG",9624]],
    PARAMETER["A0",-6259712.633486367,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8623]],
    PARAMETER["A1",0.5421061154648178,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8624]],
    PARAMETER["A2",0.929306188894481,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8625]],
    PARAMETER["B0",3067450.732242991,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8639]],
    PARAMETER["B1",0.929306188894481,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8640]],
    PARAMETER["B2",-0.5421061154648178,SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],ID["EPSG",8641]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,
    ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]
```

I am now trying to use this WKT transformation pipeline with Python to reproject raster or vector data using the GDAL Python API but I can't seem to understand how to implement it.

The GDAL C API function
[OCTNewCoordinateTransformationEx](https://gdal.org/api/ogr_srs_api.html#_CPPv432OCTNewCoordinateTransformationEx20OGRSpatialReferenceH20OGRSpatialReferenceH35OGRCoordinateTransformationOptionsH) creates a new transformation object that can use a transform pipeline but I don't see its equivalent in the Python API.

If I was to consider points only, I could use Pyproj v3.4 as it can define a transform from a pipeline using [Transformer.from_pipeline](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_pipeline).

Any recommendation on how to implement this with the GDAL Python API?

Comment: I think you need 3 match-up points to get all 6 affine parameters.

Comment: The question is more on how to use the affine parameters and not about the robustness of the transformation. I used the minimum number of points required by simil.py but 3 points would indeed provide better results ! I upated the post adding a point and updating the affine parameters.

Comment: With gdalwarp and ogr2ogr the affine transformation can be used in a +proj=affine pipeline with the -ct parameter. If you want to transform from the local to the projected (utm 13N) srs, the transformation must be the inverse of the one used in the _derived from projected_ wkt. And the target srs must be defined with a -t_srs parameter.  I don't know if you can use the derived wkt as source srs and save the pipeline, i think for compatibility reasons gdal still needs wkt1 srs. I haven't made a Python script with that process yet, in order to answer accordingly.